# MVC Route Constraint for bool

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes, constraints, boolean

What would be a valid regex for a MVC route constraint passing a bool?  For example, I have the below route:

```
routes.MapRoute("MenuRouteWithExtension",
    "Menu.mvc/{action}/{projectId}/{dealerId}/{isGroup}",
     new { controller = "Menu", action = "RedirectUrl",
           projectId = "", dealerId = "", isGroup = "" }
     new { projectId = @"\d+", dealerId = @"\d+", isGroup = @"???" });
```

Basically, I need to know what would be valid in place of the ??? in the above code example.

This way, the Action on the other end can use the bool type like:

```
public ActionResult RedirectUrl(int projectId, int dealerId, bool isGroup)
```

Thank you in advance for your input.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
isGroup = @"^(true|false)$"
```

So...

```
routes.MapRoute(
  "MenuRouteWithExtension",
  "Menu.mvc/{action}/{projectId}/{dealerId}/{isGroup}",
  new
  {
    controller = "Menu",
    action = "RedirectUrl",
    projectId = "",
    dealerId = "",
    isGroup = "" //Possibly set this to 'true' or 'false'?
  },
  new
  {
    projectId = @"^\d+$",
    dealerId = @"^\d+$",
    isGroup = "^(true|false)$"
  }
);
```

Casing shouldn't matter, so `True` should be accepted, as well as `falSE`.

Also, I've put `^` and `$` on the regex values so that they won't match, for instance `blahtrueblah`.

Comment: shouldn't dealerId = @"^\d$+", be dealerId = @"^\d+$", just switch the last 2 characters